# MacVim + tmux or: The Copy Paste Riddle

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, macvim, tmux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [copy-paste not working in MacVim when launched in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/245893/copy-paste-not-working-in-macvim-when-launched-in-tmux)

Now this is *weird*.

- Copied a chunk of a text from somewhere into clipboard.
- Ran `mvim` from a tmux buffer.
- Opened a file in MacVim.
- Pasted the text.
- *MacVim results with the error: E353: Nothing to register +*
- Nothing gets pasted.

The plot thickens: I try to copy this error -- paste fails.

I go over the same steps, this time running MacVim from a regular Terminal window (without  tmux) -- Everything is in its right place.

Whaa?

Comment: (Re: dup; I just realized that this one is older, so 245893 should probably be be the dup of this one instead. Either way, the duplication is nearly exact.)

Answer (score 3):

When you use the mvim script, a copy of Vim is launched in the background. tmux is known to do weird things with copy and paste on Mac, so tmux is probably interfering in this manner.

There is an open ticket at the tmux SF site about getting pbcopy and pbpaste to work with tmux.

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile I moved to iTerm, which has split screen features.